# Undo already merged merge request to main in gitlab

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, version-control, pycharm

Please help.

How do I undo a merged merge request i made from a feature branch to main in gitlab?
I am doing this from Pycharm git and tried hard reseting to before merge, but it doesnt let me force push after and change origin main. It forces me to merge/rebase to origin main, so I cant rewrite origin main.

I dont mind losing the changes from this feature branch. The origin feature branch has been deleted after the merge.

Should I just force push origin main from terminal instead of Pycharm like this?

```
git checkout main
git reset --hard <commit_hash_before_merge>
git push --force origin main
```

Comment: The commands you show make sense provided that it is OK to rewrite history in the remote repository (`origin`). Is your problem that the remote does not permit you to force-push into it? If so, that is what you have to fix.

Comment: Yes, thank you, you were right.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to do it via Gitlab

1. On the left sidebar, select Search or go to and find your project.
2. Select Code > Merge requests and identify your merge request.
3. Scroll to the merge request reports area, and find the report showing when the merge request was merged.
4. Select Revert.
5. In Revert in branch, select the branch to revert your changes into.
6. Optional. Select Start a new merge request to start a new merge request with the new revert commit.
7. Select Revert.

See this [Gitlab Revert changes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/revert_changes.html) for more information.

Comment: This procedure creates a new commit that undoes the changes that the merge introduced. It does not reset history; it does not forget the merge.

Comment: Yes this is true. But it will still undo the changes